# Javascript, onbeforeunload event works when submitting on a form in IE

Tags: javascript

I am writing for some adivce on a javascript I made for a xhtml page. I got it to mostly work on IE, FF and chrome (Safari still giving me some grief but thats another subject.) The problem I am having is that IE would run the beforeunload event even when someone is submitting a form which is not something i want to happen because the beforeunload script would cause the information to be reseted. It even does it when I press F5 which isn't something I want either. Now FF and Chrome aren't having that problem when the form is submitted don't know why though. Here is the code I have written so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
var hiddenBtn = document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerCloseSubmit");
return  hiddenBtn.click();
           }   </script>
```

Just wondering how to go about this any advice is very appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a html hidden variable.  Assign a value to when the user submits the form.  Then in your unload function, check that hidden variable.  If it's populated with whatever value, then leave the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (document.getElementById("wasformsubmitted").value != "Y") {
    var hiddenBtn = document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerCloseSubmit");
    return  hiddenBtn.click();
  }
}   
function SetSubmitVariables()
{
 document.getElementById("wasformsubmitted").value = "Y";
 return true;
}
</script>
<body>
  <form ... onsubmit="return SetSubmitVariables();">
    <input type="hidden" id="wasformsubmitted" value="N" />
    ... 
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Sounds good, Could you possible give me an example for reference if it is at all possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove onBeforeUnload listener from window when you submit the form

E.g. if you submit form with id="form1", then you can add this code.

```js
    document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function(){
        window.onbeforeunload=function(){};
    }
```

Comment: So I just add this to the script and add the form ID so that way it would ignore the onbeforeunload function when the submit is called? Is that how it works?

Comment: Yep. It works for me. Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/a3Zdq/ You can press "Run" to fire onBeforeUnload event.

Comment: Is there a Version of this where this script would only run if its on a IE or FireFox broswer?